# Sendmail reports that "mail loops back to me​" due to MX

Tags: centos, sendmail, mx-record

I have had [Sendmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sendmail) set up in one of my CentOS servers, and I have email marketing software running on it.

I configured Sendmail last time to make sure everything worked and everything was fine. Last week my hosting company changed my IP address and now everything is fallen apart.

I tried to send an email with mail() and it is not getting delivered. Everything is not getting delivered and sitting on the `/var/spool/mail/root`.

The error I am getting is "mail loops back to me MX problem".

In my sendmail configuration I have now changed:
LOCAL_DOMAIN to be my domain
and also added my domain to hosts

I don't know what else to do. Sorry I am a novice in [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) and SSH so if you can put the commands than just saying what to do, that will be great too.

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks for providing a workaround to the title pr0blem that doesn't break search.

Comment: @NullUserException, you're welcome, but it's not good enough.  Google and a browser's page-search will find the "problem" ***in the title***, but SE's search engine won't!

Comment: @BrockAdams It seems like it's able to find it, but [it won't highlight it](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3aproblem)

Comment: However, this question is off topic and would rather belong to http://www.serverfault.com Flagged accordingly. Friendly reminder: SO is aimed at *solving programming problems*.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this yesterday by uninstalling and reinstalling sendmail and just letting it run by default.

Something like

```
rpm -e sendmail
```

and then

```
yum install sendmail
yum install sendmail-cf
etc/init.d/sendmail start
```